# Does Azure AD B2C works with Dynamics Crm online?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am working with Azure AD B2C and I couldn't find the Dynamics CRM online option under API access(required permissions). Is there any way by which we can work with Dynamics CRM online in B2C.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in integration between Azure AD B2C and Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement that enables external customer sign-ins using local accounts and/or any federated social identity providers.

See [the **Azure AD B2C provider settings for portals** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c) for more information about configuring Azure AD B2C as an identity provider for the Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement portal.